# aligned in alignat

Tags: align, alignat

I am facing some (probably famous) issues using alignat. 
I try to break a too long equation inside alignat, by using aligned.
Nevertheless the alignment doesn't work well, the aligned environment ignores the & from alignat.

I also tried using multiline and split, but it didn't work out, too.
Thus, I would be grateful for help! Thanks in advance!

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&&\mathbb{E}(u(L_{1}^{\prime}))&\geq\mathbb{E}(u(L_{2}^{\prime})) \\
\Leftrightarrow&& \ \!\begin{aligned}[t]&u(0)q(1-t)+\underline{u(0)(1-q)(1-r)}+u(1)qt+\underline{u(1)(1-q)r} \geq \\ &u(0)q(1-s)+\underline{u(0)(1-q)(1-r)}+u(1)qs+\underline{u(1)(1-q)r}
\end{aligned}\\
\Leftrightarrow &&u(0)q(1-t)+u(1)qt&\geq u(0)q(1-s)+u(1)qs\\
\Leftrightarrow &&u(0)(1-t)+u(1)t&\geq u(0)(1-s)+u(1)s\\
\Leftrightarrow &&\mathbb{E}(u(L_{1}))&\geq\mathbb{E}(u(L_{2}))
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to get a reasonable layout with the terms fully expanded like this but perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
&&\mathbb{E}(u(L'_{1}))&\geq\mathbb{E}(u(L'_{2})) \\
&\Leftrightarrow&u(0)q(1-t)+\underline{u(0)(1-q)(1-r)}\\
&               &\qquad +u(1)qt+\underline{u(1)(1-q)r}\\
&& &\geq  u(0)q(1-s)+\underline{u(0)(1-q)(1-r)}\\
&& & \qquad +u(1)qs+\underline{u(1)(1-q)r}\\
&\Leftrightarrow &u(0)q(1-t)+u(1)qt&\geq u(0)q(1-s)+u(1)qs\\
&\Leftrightarrow &u(0)(1-t)+u(1)t&\geq u(0)(1-s)+u(1)s\\
&\Leftrightarrow &\mathbb{E}(u(L_{1}))&\geq\mathbb{E}(u(L_{2}))
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```